# React - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'front_default' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I learn best by building my own projects with things that's "fun".

I'm building a Pokedex and everything has been pretty neat, until today when building out a new function.

It's supposed to search every time the user passes in another letter with the "searchPokemon" function.
When this is assigned to the button it works like a charm, but when I try to add it to the "onChange" handler within the input it generates this:

[image]

How does that come?
If I assign an invalid pokemon name (string) and then search when the searchPokemon function is assigned to the button it doesn't generate an error message, but now it does?

I assume I need some sort of if statement, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
import Axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./SearchPokemon.css";

function PK() {
  const api = Axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/",
  });

  const [pokemonSearched, setPokemonSearched] = useState(false);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({});
  const [pokemonDescription, fetchDescription] = useState({});
  const [evolution, pokemonEvolution] = useState({});

  const searchPokemon = () => {
    api.get(`pokemon/${search}`.toLowerCase()).then((response) => {
      setPokemon({
        name: response.data.name,
        height: response.data.height,
        weight: response.data.weight,
        img: response.data.sprites.front_default,
        id: response.data.id,
        type: response.data.types[0].type.name,
        type2: response.data.types[1]?.type.name,
      });

      api.get(`pokemon-species/${response.data.id}/`).then((response) => {
        fetchDescription({
          entry: response.data.flavor_text_entries[0].flavor_text,
          evolution: response.data.evolution_chain.url,
        });
        api.get(`${response.data.evolution_chain.url}`).then((response) => {
          pokemonEvolution({
            evolution: response.data.chain.evolves_to[0]?.species.name,
          });
        });
      });
    });
    setPokemonSearched(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="page">
      <div className="search-section">
        <input
          placeholder="Search..."
          type="text"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setSearch(event.target.value);
            searchPokemon();
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={searchPokemon}>Click me</button>
      </div>
      <div className="main">
        {!pokemonSearched ? null : (
          <>
            <h1 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>{pokemon.name}</h1>
            <h1>No. {pokemon.id}</h1>
            <img src={pokemon.img} alt="" />

            <div className="info-wrapper">
              <div className="info">
                <h3 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
                  Type: {pokemon.type} {pokemon.type2}
                </h3>
                <h3>Height: {pokemon.height * 10} Cm</h3>
                <h3>Weight: {pokemon.weight / 10} Kg</h3>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="desc">
              <div className="desc-info">
                <h3 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
                  {pokemonDescription.entry}
                </h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default PK;
```

Comment: I see you have already added conditional chaining (`response.data.types[1]?.type.name`). Try recreating the problematic query and log the response you get, so you can see exactly what your data looks like when that happens, and post it here.

Comment: I tried to remove that but I get the same issue.

Do you mean this?
type2: (_response$data$types$ = response.data.types[1]) === null || _response$data$types$ === void 0 ? void 0 : _response$data$types$.type.name

Answer (score 0):

The error tells exactly what the problem is!

You cannot read property `type` of undefined.

So what does that mean? You have on line `23` the following:

`type2: response.data.types[1]?.type.name,`

<s>As you are using Typescript, so you have to understand what exactly the `?` means on that line, which is just you making an assumption that the properties followed by the `?` will be present everytime! Even though the typing says otherwise.</s>

But, as you can see in the docs of the [pokemon endpoint](https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon), types is a list, and some don't have more than 1 type in the array, so you have to figure out a way of checking weather that typing is present to set the state.

Edit: As you are triggering the searchPokemon function on every keyboard stroke (try doing the same [here](https://pokeapi.co/)), you are using the hook setPokemon on every response, even when there's no `response.data`, so here's what causing you trouble, you just need to find a way to validate the response before updating the state.

Comment: Hey Kseikyo, thanks for your answer!
I appreciate this, this is done to learn.

First of, I am not familiar with Typescript, from what I've learned about Javascript the ? is an if statement itself, that can select within 2 different options with the help of :, like I've done here "!pokemonSearched ? null :".
I don't really get how this can be done within the state "setPokemon" (I assume it has to be done here).

Am I on the right track going about this with some sort of statement like this: "type2: response.data.types[1]?.type.name:null,"

Comment: Also, how can this work when it's assigned to a button but not when it's set on onChange?
If you press the button with an invalid pokemon, nothing happens, but as soon as I do this when I type and I type 1 letter this issue gets generated.

Comment: @Ribz oh I thought the error you were getting was after pressing the button, as the question does not mention typing name and searching, will adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the update,
I get the idea that it messes up when it tries to call something that doesn't exist (you are using the hook setPokemon on every response, even when there's no response.data, so here's what causing you trouble), but I don't understand why it doesn't render the same problem if I use the button, if I write for example "d" as in "Ditto" and press the button, nothing happens, if I also then type "I" and press the search button, nothing happens, it doesn't break.

So I wonder why it "works" when it's attached to the button.
Thanks in advanced!